# org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-4.x

I've recently upgraded hibernate version from 3.0 to 4.0 and most of the things were working fine except when I tried to save list of entities. If I save each entity separately I'm not getting any exception but when I try to save the entire list, getting the following exception:

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList

code:

```
this.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(entityObject) // Results in exception
```

Session configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="domain">
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530572/org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity) they have already solved the problem

Comment: A related question: [java - How to save multiple objects via ArrayList in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923108/how-to-save-multiple-objects-via-arraylist-in-hibernate).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a collection of objects to the session object for persisting. As per the [Session javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#saveOrUpdate(java.lang.Object)), the save accepts a Object of the persistent class

see if this answer helps you : [Hibernate saveOrUpdate large data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083284/hibernate-saveorupdate-large-data)